# c# - How to deal with decimal

Tags: c#, database, winforms, numericupdown

I have a numericUpDown and set the decimal places on properties to 3 so it became 0.000

Here is the code

```
Decimal inputGrossWeight = numGrossWeight.Value;

if (inputGrossWeight = 0.000)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Gross Weight must be filled!");
}
else 
{
   Data newData = new Data();
   newData.grossWeight = inputGrossWeight;
}
```

note:

- numGrossWeight is the name of numericUpDown
- grossWeight is the column name on my database

and I store it to database with the data type float

So when user type in 2.365 it will stored to database 2.365 too.

i've tried using many ways and it give me error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'double'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
>
> Literal of type double cannot be implicitly converted to type
>   'decimal'; use an 'M' suffix to create a literal of this type

What wrong with my code?

Comment: First problem: you're using `=` when you want `==`. Second problem: you're using `0.000` which is a `double` literal; you want `0.000m` so it's a `decimal` literal, exactly as the second compiler error tells you. (It's not clear which line is causing the first error...)

Comment: the error message is telling you exactly what is wrong

Comment: The error clearly sais what to do, doesn´t it? "An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: Third problem, expecting that 2.365 as a decimal will be stored *exactly* as 2.365 in the database if the data type is float.

Comment: I just realize when I re-check my entity model, the grossWeight was signed type double, but on my database the grossWeight column signed data type as float.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to assign in your `if` statement.

try this rather

```
if (inputGrossWeight == 0m)
```

As Jon Skeet mentioned in his comment, by adding the `m` you are making sure that you are using a `decimal` literal and thus comparing apples to apples.

Comment: it works with adding "m" on it, but I still don't understand, what "m" used to?

Comment: Adding the `m` makes it a decimal literal, as Jon Skeet mentioned. When you do not have it, it is a double literal.